# Equal results in K-cross validation of two models - R

Tags: r, analytics

I have the following linear models:

```
gn<- lm(NA.~ I(PC^0.25) + I(((PI)^2)),data=DSET)
gndos<-update(gn,subset=-c(1,2,4,10,11,26,27,100,158))
```

I run K-cross validation in each model and the results are the same:

```
 library(DAAG)
a<-CVlm(df=DSET,form.lm = gn ,m=5)
t<-CVlm(df=DSET,form.lm = gndos ,m=5)
```

I would like to know the error in my code.

EDIT:

I show a reproducible example with simulated values. Here's my example:

```
set.seed(1234)
    PC<-rnorm(600,mean=50,sd=4)
    PI<-rnorm(600,mean=30,sd=4)
    NA. <- 20*PC - 1.725*PI + rnorm(600,sd=1)
    zx<-data.frame(NA.,PC,PI)
    hn<- lm(NA.~ I(PC^0.25) + I(((PI)^2)),data=zx)
    hndos<-update(hn,subset=-c(1,2,4,10,11,26,27,100,158))
library(DAAG)
    a<-CVlm(df=zx,form.lm = hn ,m=5)
    a<-CVlm(df=zx,form.lm = hndos ,m=5)
```

So, with this reproducible example, the results of the cross-validations are the same for each model too.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your Question. Where does `CVlm()` come from? Why all those `()` in the quadratic term in the formula? Is your space bar broken? More constructively; either those observations have no/little influence on the model or they were not in the first model, perhaps due to `NA`s? Without a reproducible example, we'll just be guessing, and such Q&A's are not a good fit for [so].

Comment: CVlm comes from the DAAG package. Take a look carefully and "NA." is the name of the variable. Statistically, gndos model uses the data set of gn model but without high-leverage points.

Comment: I did look closely' `NA.` is not what R considers to be `NA`, i.e. missing, but you've answered my question as these can't be high leverage points and `NA`. Like I said, I can't begin to guess what is wrong without a **reproducible** example; please provide one. Failing that, try fitting `gndos` by hand rather than via `update`. Look at `gndos` and see if it really has fewer observations in it. Make sure **DAAG** is up-to-date.

Comment: See my edit with a reproducible example :) .

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example - with that I was motivated to install the packages and step through the code under the debugger, which quickly demonstrated the problem as I explain in my Answer. This is why we ask for reproducible examples. Do note that you are overwriting `a` in the example, and the alignment has gone awry...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how `CVlm()` collects the data used to fit the model. It does this through the `form.lm` object, but this is not sufficient to reproduce the data used to fit the model. I would consider this a bug, but a deficiency might be more correct.

Because you used `subset` in the `lm()` call, the data used to fit that model included 591 observations. But you can't tell this from the formula alone. `CVlm()` does the following

```
form <- formula(hndos)
mf <- model.frame(form, zx)

R> nrow(mf)
[1] 600
```

Ahh, there are 600 observations. What it should have done was simply take

```
mf <- model.frame(hndos) ## model.frame(form.lm) in their code

R> nrow(mf)
[1] 591
```

Then the CV results would have been different. The code in `CVlm()` needs to be a little more nuanced than simply grabbing the formula of an `lm()` object if that is what is supplied to it. This would also be pretty easy to solve too.